# Some simple JSTL logic error

Tags: jsp, jstl

This is the error I encounter when trying to run the code bellow it.

```
org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "?" "? "" at line 2, column 9.
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    "." ...
    "(" ...
    "[" ...
```

Under is the code I am trying to use, but it seems the logic is off? First time using JSTL so a pointer to how to this would be nice :) 
betalingstatus is a boolean variable in "d".

```
${d.betalingstatus
    ? <td align="center">Betaling mottatt</td>
    : <td><button type="submit" name="betaling" value="${d.mobilnummer}">Registrer betaling</button></td>}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
${d.betalingstatus
? '<td align="center">Betaling mottatt</td>'
    : '<td><button type="submit" name="betaling" value="'+${d.mobilnummer}+'">Registrer betaling</button></td>'}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues.

1) The strings inside the ternary operator have to be surrounded with apostrophes, but

2) You cannot concatenate strings within a ternary operator.

As a personal preference for readability, I would also include the == in the condition.

So I would do this:

```
<c:set var="tButtonString" value="<td><button type=\"submit\" name=\"betaling\" value=\"${d.mobilnummer}\">Registrer betaling</button></td>"/>
${d.betalingstatus == true ? '<td align="center">Betaling mottatt</td>' : tButtonString}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
${d.betalingstatus ? '<td align=\"center\">Betaling mottatt</td>':  
'<td><button type=\"submit\" name=\"betaling\" value=\"'+d.mobilnummer+'\">
Registrer betaling</button></td>'}
```